# Reading a value from String to String Array in Java

Tags: java, arrays, string

How to read a String into a String array in java , I have the following code :

```
for (int i=0 ; i<=jArr2.length() ; i++ ) {
    JSONObject jArrOb = jArr2.getJSONObject(i);
    String empIDStr = jArrOb.getString("emp_id");
    String[] plant_ID[i] = empIDStr;             
}
```

The compiler shows an error stating that String cannot be read into String Array. I am basically moving the values of JSON object into a String Array.

Answer (score 2):

You need to initialize the String array before the loop:

```
int n = jArr2.length();
String[] plant_ID = new String[n];

for (int i=0 ; i<n ; i++ )
{
     JSONObject jArrOb = jArr2.getJSONObject(i);
     String empIDStr = jArrOb.getString("emp_id");
     plant_ID[i] = empIDStr; 
                
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following where you create the array first.
Make sure to change the upper bound of your for loop to avoid an Array out of bounds exception.

```
String[] plant_ids = new String[jArr2.length];
for (int i=0; i<jArr2.length(); i++ ) {
   JSONObject jArrOb = jArr2.getJSONObject(i);
   String empIDStr = jArrOb.getString("emp_id");
   plant_ids[i] = empIDStr;             
}
```

Comment: Thank you , it worked.....only modification required in your code was I had to type length() instead of length